# sequelize.js - You need to install mysql package manually

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

After installing node.js and sequelize.js, and running a basic test, the message "You need to install mysql package manually" is displayed.

I've tried searching the web and Stackoverflow for the cause of this message.

I have installed:

- mysql server version 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
- node v0.10.5
- sequelize.js v1.6.0

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to install the `mysql` [npm module](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql):

`npm install mysql`

The reason sequelize doesn't have the mysql module as its own dependency is because it can be used with other databases such as postgres or sqlite.

Comment: Why did you specify exactly this alpha version? Wouldn't `npm install mysql` be enough and more useable for future reference? (current npm-module  version is alpha9).

Comment: Well, responding to my own doubts: The sequelize.js module officially works with the modules `mysql@~2.0.0-alpha7` and `sequelize-mysql`: http://sequelizejs.com/documentation

Comment: Although accepted, your answer doesn't answer the question. **What's the cause** for this massage?

Comment: @borisdiakur The lack of installing the mysql module; it seems fairly obvious.

Comment: @DaveNewton The part that was not fairly obvious is why the mysql module is not listed as a direct dependency of sequelize per default. Meanwhile go-oleg has edited his answer accordingly. +1

Answer (score 20):

Install mysql globally:

```
npm install -g mysql
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer because locally mysql will be installed for all. This is the tricky one.

Comment: -g means install globally.

Answer (score 9):

For 2017+ users who are using `mysql2`, the `mysql` requirement was part of Sequelize v3.

Install v4 of Sequelize (ie. `npm i sequelize@4.23.0 --save`) and it will work properly with `mysql2`.

For more info, see [this issue in the github repo](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6546).

Answer (score 7):

```
// Using NPM
$ npm install --save sequelize

# And one of the following:
$ npm install --save pg pg-hstore
$ npm install --save mysql2
$ npm install --save sqlite3
$ npm install --save tedious // MSSQL
```

Comment: it would be nice if you are gonna add description about this solution

Answer (score 3):

I had tried 'npm install mysql' as it is a few times (OCD maybe), but it didn't do the trick. What actually made a difference was the answer by Svagis above:

```
npm install -g mysql
```

Now I get an access denied error, which is more of a relief because it means progress.

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, it is suggested to keep these library local to the project, so that it can be packaged and installed in other machines by npm.

Answer (score 1):

i try to install package mysql and mysql2. It works!

npm install mysql2 --save

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the mysql npm module.

```
npm install --save mysql2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I tried following all the steps above.
Nothing worked. Finally, found that the sequelize-cli I installed not global so it was not able to find the mysql2 module.

So I ran the following commands.

```
npm uninstall sequelize-cli
npm install sequelize-cli -g --force // --force removed the previous bin files
```

And finally, it worked :)