# i can start my nodejs server is showing Please install mysql2 package manually

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
/Users/macbookair/apps/ussd/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:55
        throw new Error(`Please install ${moduleName} package manually`);
        ^

Error: Please install mysql2 package manually
    at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (/Users/macbookair/apps/ussd/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:55:15)
    at new ConnectionManager (/Users/macbookair/apps/ussd/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:30:21)
    at new MysqlDialect (/Users/macbookair/apps/ussd/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:13:30)
    at new Sequelize (/Users/macbookair/apps/ussd/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:194:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macbookair/apps/ussd/model/db.js:30:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)

Node.js v18.17.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
rs
```

Tried `npm i mysql2` but it fails to run

Comment: There really isn't enough information to answer your question shown in your post.  Is there any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing how to reproduce the error?

Comment: However, I do see Sequelize in your traceback, so perhaps one of [Error: Please install mysql2 package manually when using pkg with Sequelize MySQL in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77117963) or [ERROR: Please install mysql2 package manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50614067) or [Sequelize - Please install mysql2 package manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65664664) or [Install mysql2 package manually - error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51086021) or [sequelize.js - You need to install mysql package manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17667368) may apply to you also.